# Distributed Cache Service error

Tags: distributed-cache, automationanywhere

I installed Automation Anywhere controlroom and at the loginform I get the error:

> "Distributed Cache Service has problem. Please contact to Admin"

How can I debug/fix this?

Comment: Please provide some more information, and include what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Distributed Cache Services should be installed while doing the setup. If you are doing controlroom installation on a single machine, do select all the services, should work

There is installation guide for isolated and distributed env... please check which one you are opting.